# ASP.NET Web Forms Routing returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm sure this is something simple that I am overlooking -- but it seems odd.

In my ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms application, I've declared the following code in my "Global.asax" file.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
...
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
....
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.MapPageRoute("404", "{*url}", "~/Page-Not-Found.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "about", "~/Default.aspx");
}
```

I've tried different variations in the order of adding the routes, also different ways of declaring the URL for "about" with and without parameters, and removing the 404 route.

The 404 redirect works fine to redirect to "Page-Not-Found.aspx".

Web.config contains the following

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Any ideas why the "about" rule would not work?  When I try to go to it, or any other valid route I create it just goes to a 404 page.  The 404 redirect route above works fine (because it's showing the themed page).  However, removing the 404 route renders just a standard .NET/IIS 404 page when I try to browse to the "about" route.

Comment: I guess I should add, that I'm developing using Visual Studio 2010 and testing directly from VS using the ASP.NET Development Server it launches, running ASP.NET version 4.0.30319.18408

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you are missing a "/"

I'm using this redirect and it is working fine :

```
routes.MapPageRoute("productTour", "tour/", "~/ProductTour.aspx");
```

I think also the name of the route can not be empty.

In our case, address will be : http://www.oursite.com/tour

Comment: Gave that a try and no luck unfortunately.  Tried adding the ending "/" and also tried giving it a name.  I also just tried to create a folder structure for "corporate" and creating a "corporate/about" route, but no luck.

Comment: Do you have any error messages ? or page just don't load ?

Comment: And be aware! If you already have a folder named “about”, the route will not work, your actual default (or index) for this folder will be called

Comment: It's a 404 error.  My redirect actually works just fine, which is weird.  It's the only route that works.  Disabling that route renders just a standard .NET/IIS 404 error when I try to go to a "friendly" URL I created a route for.

Comment: I’m really not sure, but if you disable your 404 redirect, is other route working? I think you redirect all your request to your 404 route.

Comment: Honestly sorry, I cannot see what is wrong with your code. Seems good to me 

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I'm not sure what the issue is either.  Disabling the 404 route doesn't make any difference.  Hmm.. srange

Answer (score 0):

Not the best of answers, and not sure why it resolved it -- however, publishing the site to an IIS 7 server rendered the routing working.

It must be an issue with the version of the ASP.NET Development Server with VS 2010.